# fetch inside of then() doesn't work the first time onClick()

Tags: javascript, api

So I am trying to make a form that when it is submitted this code is called.

```
async function addListing() {
        let listing: any = {
            make: make,
            model: model,
            year: year,
            mileage: mileage,
            price: price
        };

        await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/listing", {
            method: "POST", 
            headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"},
            body: JSON.stringify(listing)
        })
        .then(() => {
            fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/listing")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                setListingID(data[data.length - 1].id);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Listing: ", listingId, " Seller: ", sellerId)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
```

The post function works fine however the get function inside the first then() doesn't work the first time the button it is clicked.
So the first time I click on the submit button I get: "Listing:    Seller:  3"
And the second time (and each time after that) it is correct for example: "Listing: 123   Seller:  3"

I tried all of yesterday to find a solution I made a separate function and it wasn't working Today I searched up the whole internet tried a bunch of things but I can't seem to find what I did wrong.

When I get this to work I want to use that listingId function in order to call another function which will connect the listingId and sellerId in a separate table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a false assumption in your debugging. The `.then()` callback in question is invoking an asynchronous operation, but nothing ever *awaits* that operation.  So it's *immediately* moving to the next `.then()` in the chain.

Return the `Promise`:

```
.then(() => {
  return fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/listing")
     .then(/* etc... */);
})
```

Taking a step back... Mixing `await` and `.then()` callbacks is a recipe for confusion.  Since you're using async/await, why not use async/await?  For example:

```
try {
  await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/listing", {
    method: "POST", 
    headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"},
    body: JSON.stringify(listing)
  });
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/listing");
  const data = await res.json();
  setListingID(data[data.length - 1].id);
  console.log("Listing: ", listingId, " Seller: ", sellerId);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

---

**Additionally...**

Is this React?:

```
setListingID(data[data.length - 1].id);
```

If so, please see [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/328193)

State updates are asynchronous (and *not* awaitable).  If you need that value immediately after invoking a state update, store it in a variable.  For example:

```
const data = await res.json();
const newListingID = data[data.length - 1].id;
setListingID(newListingID);
console.log("Listing: ", newListingID, " Seller: ", sellerId);
```

Comment: Damn okay yeah I forgot about useState that was it. Thank you so much for the help.